# Hide mat-tooltip immediately when mouse leaves button

Tags: angular, angular-material

Latest Angular Material v13 upgrade is causing this mattooltip issue

When a button is hovered it shows tooltip and overlaps with the adjacent controls not allowing to click until mouse is moved away from the tooltip

How can I immediately close this mattooltip when mouse pointer leaves its parent control (Action Button) and access the adjacent controls (Tooltip Position dropdown)

example here https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#positioning

[image: tooltip overlap with other controls]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For some reason this setting is not exposed on the directive itself, but is set on a global level on the `MatTooltipDefaultOptions`.

What you're looking for is the `disableTooltipInteractivity` property, which makes the tooltip not disappear when hovered, making the inner text selectable.

You'll need to provide your custom `MatTooltipDefaultOptions` (either on module level or component level) with the value set to false.

Working stackblitz (see app.module.ts) [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wctyvm).

Comment: answer on github angular here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24689

Comment: Recommend calling MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS_FACTORY() to get the default options and only overriding the ones you need to. Here is the provider syntax: { provide: MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: matTooltipDefaultOptions },

Comment: [Stackblitz example using MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS_FACTORY](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wctyvm-pisgmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)